# Functional body of a program

Tags: language-agnostic

What is the "functional body" of a program?

I thought it was its functions' prototypes, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the code that actually gets executed, so that would be the code inside your methods.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, many programs have no functional parts.

Seriously, you are over-thinking this. It doesn't mean much. It's the human code that actually generates machine code. The machine finds all our comments rather useless and non-functional.